# How are things purchased in AoT?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In Attack on Titans, how exactly was everything paid for? Not once in AoT so far did I ever see any exchanging of currency. For example the Markets:

[image]

How do businesses make money then? Is there a type of currency in AoT that they officially use?

For example do they just give away meat for free?

[image]

Are Potatoes, Vegetables and cutlery such as plates, bowls and cups free or have I just missed something?

[image]

Note: I think food is free for the survey corps or the people that are training to enlist in the army and be able to leave outside of the walls but what about everyone else? Is it free or is it paid for? If it is then whats the currency? Coins, notes *(obviously probably not :P)* or is there some sort of system where they trade for example their bit of farm land for a lot of cured meat or fish or vegetables for example.

So my question is how exactly are things purchased in AoT?

Comment: I'd say it is irrelevant to the storyline. The story is more about physical fighting rather than political/economy war, so I think the author would put more thought into making the physical fights more interesting than giving details to how people live their lives normally (like anyone could live normally after the titans invades the walls).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's definitely a monetary system in place (note I'm on mobile so I can't link any sources yet).

In episode 1, after the incident where Moses's arm is handed to his mother, there is a person saying "its like our taxes go to fatten them up". This clearly indicates some form of tax system.

In episode 6, the titans yet again breach another wall. There's a scene where merchants are blocking the passageway trying to get their goods through. This shows an obvious ownership of goods.

In the same episode, we see Mikasa and her mom targeted by slave traders. The slave traders planned to sell them to some rich folk, demonstrating value and a need for some form of money.

In episode 23, we can clearly see corrupt military police selling goods for what is obviously currency.

Over all we see several trends that point to the use of currency within Attack on Titan.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in episode 23 two members of the Military Police are seen selling some 3DMG for what is most definitely coin

Comment: Mind showing a snippet of this and at what part in the episode?

Comment: from about 7:30 i'd get a screenshot but crunchyroll is being anal

Answer (score -1):

I saw some characters use a paper currency to buy passage onto the surface from the Underground in an OVA.

Comment: Which OVA? What episode? When?